# Solr: move single document to another collection

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have system with user defined collections, in which the user can create and remove collections. For example the user has defined two collections named `Germany` and `France` to which domuments are manually add per the user's criteria.

Now I need to give the user the option to move a document (that was added, indexed and proccessed in the `Germany` collection) to the `France` collection.

I looked at the MIGRATE option in the Collections API, but it is not suited for user picked single documents.

A copy & delete could also work.

Is there any way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you read the document from `Germany` collection and then add that to `France` and then once it is successfully added , just delete the doc from `Germany` collection.

somehthing like this to delete the doc

`http://localhost:8983/solr/core_name/update?commit=true&stream.body=<delete><query>write query which can identify that single doc</query></delete>`